# Formula for designing Lynn's low pass filter

Tags: filter-design

For the second order Lynn's low pass filter, the general form of the transfer function is:
$$
H(z)=\frac{(1−z^{-m})^2}{ (1−z^{-1})^2 }
$$
where $m$ is a positive integer. The gain for this is $m^2$, time delay is $m-1$ samples and the nominal frequency corresponding to the location of the lowest frequency zero is $f_l = f_s /m$. The frequency response is given by:
$$
|H(e^{j\omega T})|=\frac{\sin^2(m\omega /2f_s)}{\sin^2(\omega /2f_s)}
$$
At the 3 dB cutoff frequency, for unit gain we have:
$$
|H(e^{j\omega_c T})|=\frac{\sin^2(m\omega_c /2f_s)}{m^2\sin^2(\omega_c /2f_s)} \\ \therefore  \frac{1}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sin^2(m\pi f_c /f_s)}{m^2\sin^2(\pi f_c /f_s)}
$$

Now, to design the filter for our required cutoff frequency $f_c$ and sampling frequency $f_s$, we need to find the value of $m$ corresponding to these inputs.
So how can we get this equation to the form $m = f(f_c, f_s)$, so that we can avoid getting the $m$ value by trial-and-error or numerical methods? Or is there some other quick approximation formula that we can use?

Comment: Hi! I've never heard of "Lynn's low pass filters", could you link us to a resource? To me, your $H(z)$ is a 2-stage CIC filter's system function with a $m$-th band low pass behaviour. Design methodology for these is *relatively* rich, because they're used everywhere that the exact spectral shape matters way less than the performance of an implementation in hardware, but there's only one parameter to change: $m$; and as you've noticed that directly gives you the position of the first zero – so, basically, I think you've answered your own question!

Comment: (i.e. your $m$ needs to be small enough that the $f_l> f_c$, and although you could rather sensibly numerically optimize, you could also try out the maybe 4 candidates for $m$ that remain.)

Comment: Which gives raise to a whole different question: These filters are mathematically cool (they are FIR, but can be built from very few very low-complexity recursive elements). Why are you using them, however, when you're trying to achieve a specific $f_c$?

Comment: @Marcus Müller, the Lynn filters are described in Chapter 7 here: https://fdocuments.in/document/biomedical-digital-signal-processing-tompkins.html

Comment: "Biomed signal processing for the IBM PC": that's historically interesting...

Comment: It is used in real-time portable ECG devices to have a cutoff frequency under 15 Hz as described here:https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse474/18wi/labs/l8/QRSdetection.pdf. Sampling frequency of at least 200 Hz is required to accurately determine the RR intervals of the heart beats. All this needs to be done on tiny MCUs so computational efficiency is required. The Lynn filter ensures this by having only integer coefficients and recursive elements as you noticed.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Both your book and that paper are written with early- to mid-80 technology in mind. These filters were chosen not because they are good filters, but because CPUs that you wouldn't have used in the last 30 years were too slow to compute anything better. Forget about them, and get some up-to-date literature, **unless** these filters are somehow standardized for specific diagnostics.

Comment: It's still relevant for us because the latest commonly available Microcontrollers for wearable devices have CPU speeds ~100MHz. Coming back to the question, the cutoff frequency is much lower than the nominal frequency. We are interested in the cutoff frequency to isolate signals of interest.

Comment: you're off the mark of what a 100 MHz processor can do in real time by maybe a factor of 1000. Filtering ECG signals in real time is really ridiculously easy. Remember that a budget-level 48 MHz arm  cortex-M4f has about 20 times the RAM built in that an IBM PC had, and unlike that, can do multiplications in a few instructions, even having dedicated floating point logic; and I'm definitely not talking about wearable devices with 100 MHz processors and Megabytes of RAM. There **can** be good reasons to use low-complexity recursive filters, namely the group delay, but they don't

Comment: seem to be the reason those were chosen, at all. So, really, your literature is obsolete, sorry. On modern CPUs/FPUs, it doesn't even make a difference if you do or do not multiply with a non-unit coefficient before accumulating, in many cases! You'd win nothing by using these kinds of filters. If you want to build a filter that selects a specific band in your ECG signal, it would be wisest to simply define a maximum acceptable group delay, and design a filter for that, instead of trying to shoehorn a specifically inflexible filter type into this.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your suggestions and we will look at alternatives too. But even with this efficient algorithm, we have actually already hit the processing bottleneck with a sampling frequency of 200 Hz with our prototype MCU. And our target sample rate is 500 Hz! There is much more that happens apart from getting these signals filtered; like extracting the ECG features, sending them over Bluetooth periodically etc. to name a few. And with 500 Hz, we will have only 2 ms to do this before the processing for the next sample starts.

Comment: You'd rarely process a single sample alone. Even then, you realize that at 100 MHz, 2 ms means 200,000 clock cycles? That is *a lot*. I don't see any bottleneck at all, to be honest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, we have got an approximation solution for this. Consider the equation:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sin^2(m\pi f_c /f_s)}{m^2\sin^2(\pi f_c /f_s)}
$$

In the right-hand side denominator, since $f_c << f_s$, we can write: $$sin(\pi f_c /f_s) \simeq \pi f_c /f_s$$
Also, in the numerator, since $f_l = f_s/m$, we have $m\pi f_c /f_s = \pi f_c /f_l$. Now, since $f_c < f_l$, we see that $0 < \pi f_c /f_l < \pi$. This means we can use [Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976462/a-1-400-years-old-approximation-to-the-sine-function-by-mahabhaskariya-of-bhaska) and write:
$$sin(m\pi f_c /f_s) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -(m\pi f_c /f_s)) (m\pi f_c /f_s)}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -(m\pi f_c /f_s)) (m\pi f_c /f_s)}\qquad $$
Plugging these back into the main equation, simplifying and solving the resulting quadratic equation for $m$, we get:
$$ m \simeq 0.3f_s/f_c$$
This gives quite accurate results. For example, if we need to design the filter for a sampling frequency of 200 Hz and cutoff frequency of 15 Hz, we get $m$ as 4. This gives us $|H(e^{j\omega_c T})|= 0.75$

Comment: @Marcus Müller you may find it interesting to note that in a more recent [article](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/58.php) a comparison is made between Lynn's moving average filter with $m = 32$ and standard linear phase FIR filters, which would require more than 100 taps to match the performance of Lynn's filter.

Comment: True-linear phase characteristic that this filter has is an important requirement to preserve the relative timing of the peaks and features of the ECG waveform.

Answer (score 1):

Just analyzing your equation, let $a = f_c / f_s$

Also we know that for $m = k/(2a)$ it reduces to $1/(m^2 sin(\pi a))$ for odd $k$ and $0$ for even $k$.

$$\lim_{m \to 0} \frac{sin^2( \pi m a)}{m^2 sin(\pi a)} = \frac{a^2 \pi^2}{sin(\pi a)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Even for this case, determining $a$ is not an easy task. I computed numerically the curve defined by this equation.

[image]

Comment: good news: $m\in \mathbb N$